# How do I use an inputvalue to locate a cell that contains the same value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an ERP-system that stores data in a different worksheet, now I want to create a macro that asks you to type in an ID number and using that input it will locate the row of which the input value matches the ID number. The archive with all the data already generates an ID number for each row.

I have no clue how to solve this as I'm pretty new to VBA and programming in general (3 days so far)

Edit: I also will probably need to add an If statement for the inputValue not matching any of the ID numbers in the list

```
Sub PullBackUp()
    inputvalue = Application.InputBox("Type ID number", "Pull a delivery-note back up", Type:=1)

    If inputvalue = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Please type an ID number to proceed"
    Else  
        'Locate the row with the ID number from the inputValue
    End If
End Sub
```

I expect to get the entire row in which the data has been put in using the ID number I get with `inputValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming IDs are unique and in column A:A you can put this in your Else clause:

```
idRow = columns("A:A").find(what:=InputValue).row
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Comment: This gives me the column number right? I `MsgBox idRow` and it returned 4 when I typed 3 in the inputbox (ID starts at 1 in A2 and increases by +1 for each row down). So i can now use `idRow` to find which column the data is in and then do some sort of `idRow.copy.entirerow` to the destination I want it to go to?

Comment: are you there? I can't figure out how I go about using the returned value, I haven't used `columns` before

Comment: You can use Rows(idRow).Copy

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your column is `B`:

```
Range("B1").End(xlDown).Find(What:=inputValue, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

For your information: I went to "Developer" menu item, and recorded a macro while performing a search in column `B`.

Comment: Does that mean this code will perform different in VBA?

Comment: When you put this code inside your `Else`-clause, it should work (if your column is `B`, otherwise you might need to adapt this piece of code).

Comment: With that code I get a type mismatch error, I tried putting it inside the if statement and also outisde and commenting out the if statement.

Comment: I changed `Range("B1")` to `sheets("Arkiv").range("A1")`